# Complex semi-simple Lie algebra dimension $5$.

Tags: lie-algebras

This is a follow-up question [Semi-simple complex lie algebras dimension $4,5,7$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4582726/semi-simple-complex-lie-algebras-dimension4-5-7?noredirect=1#comment9647212_4582726), which I need to ask some specific question about (which has a different approach than in the question above):

By root decomposition of every semisimple algebra we have $\dim(L)=\dim(H)+\vert\Phi\vert$ with $\dim(H)\le \frac 12|\Phi|$. So if there were a semi-simple Lie Algebra $\dim 5$, using only dimension equations above, we can only get the possibility that $\dim(H)=1$ and $|\Phi|=4$, which corresponds to $\Phi=\{\pm\alpha,\pm\beta\}$ and we know that $L$ would have $\mathfrak {sl}(2,\mathbb C)$ inside.

Is this the contradiction that we can write $\mathfrak {sl}(2,\mathbb C)$ in two different ways as follows?

$\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb C)\cong L_\alpha\oplus L_{-\alpha} \oplus H$,
$\mathfrak {sl}(2,\mathbb C)\cong L_\beta\oplus L_{-\beta} \oplus H$

But I cannot conclude the contradiction?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez OP's problem (see linked question and answer) seems to be that they are not allowed to "know" at this point that root systems of complex semisimple LAs are reduced. We are wondering if one can prove the result without using something equivalent to that fact. (I doubt it).

Comment: @OP: It seems that you *do* know that if $\alpha$ is any root, then there is an element $h_\alpha \in H$ such that $L_\alpha \oplus L_{-\alpha} \oplus \mathbb C h_\alpha \simeq \mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb C)$. Is that true, and can we assume that? (Because I think it would help a lot.) If you do not know that, how do you know that in the case you assume here ($\lvert \Phi \rvert = 4$) one would have those decompositions you claim?

Comment: Hi, yes I know that that's why, like you have said, i did the decomposition of sl2

Answer (score 1):

As I have said in comments and the answer to the linked question: If we do not know at this point that the "roots" (defined as non-zero weights of a Cartan subalgebra) form a (reduced) root system, then at the very least one needs the result of Lemma 2 below. The proofs below (and I know no other) need a version of Jacobson-Morozov as well as representation theory of $\mathfrak{sl}_2$. (Which makes me think it is better to use this machinery a little further to show, once and for all, that the roots form a reduced root system; in fact, Lemma 2 shows the "reduced" part in general.)

Let $\alpha, \beta$ be two proportional roots, i.e. there is $c\in \mathbb C$ such that $\beta = c \alpha$.

**Lemma 1**: $c \in \{\pm \frac12, \pm 1, \pm 2 \}$.

Proof: You say you know there are $x_\alpha \in L_\alpha, y_{-\alpha} \in L_{-\alpha}, h_\alpha \in H$ such that $\alpha(h_\alpha)=2$ and
$$\mathfrak{s}(\alpha) := \mathbb C x_\alpha \oplus \mathbb C y_{-\alpha} \oplus \mathbb C h_\alpha \simeq \mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb C).$$

Note that for any $\beta \in \Phi$,

$$\bigoplus_{i \in \mathbb Z} L_{\beta + i \alpha}$$

(where the summands are understood to be $=0$ in case $\beta + i \alpha \notin \Phi \cup \{0\}$) is a $\mathfrak{sl}_2$-representation via the action of $\mathfrak{s}(\alpha)$ on it: It is the $\mathfrak{s}(\alpha)$-module generated by $L_\beta$. In all such representations, all eigenvalues of $h_\alpha$ are integers; but on $L_\beta$, by definition $h_\alpha$ operates via multiplication with $\beta(h_\alpha)$. So $c = \frac{\beta(h_\alpha)}{\alpha(h_\alpha)} \in \frac12 \mathbb Z$.

Now, $\beta = c \alpha \Leftrightarrow \alpha = c^{-1} \beta$, and $\pm \frac12, \pm 1, \pm 2$ are the only elements of $\frac12 \mathbb Z$ whose reciprocals are also in $\frac12 \mathbb Z$.

**Lemma 2**: If all root spaces $L_\alpha$ are one-dimensional (which they are here), necessarily $c \in \{\pm 1\}$.

Proof: Assume on the contrary that there is $\alpha \in \Phi$ with $2\alpha \in \Phi$. With the notation of Lemma 1, consider the case $\alpha = \beta$, i.e. the $\mathfrak s(\alpha)$-module $$\bigoplus_{i \in \mathbb Z} L_{i \alpha}.$$

$\mathfrak{sl}_2$-representation theory tells us that the maps $[x_\alpha, \cdot ]: L_{i\alpha} \rightarrow L_{(i+1)\alpha}$ are surjective for $i \ge 0$. But if $L_\alpha$ has dimension $1$, it is spanned by $x_\alpha$, so that map is the zero map already for $i=1$.

**Corollary**: If $\dim(H)=1$, then $\lvert \Phi \rvert =2$.

---

Note: I am nitpicky in Lemma 2 because in more general situations, over other fields, there can be root spaces of dimension $\ge 2$ and non-reduced root systems, cf. [Examples of Lie algebras of the $BC$ root system type](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3132957/96384) or [Where does non-reduced root system come up?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3346077/96384) and links there. You seem to be saying you know already that the root spaces are one-dimensional. That in itself is something for which, to my knowledge, one already needs this $\mathfrak{sl}_2$-machinery. As for non-circular arguments to show it, cf. [How to show this $L$-module is simple? (related to the root space decomposition of semisimle Lie algebras)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3135978/96384), also https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4355610/96384. The issue recently came up in the question [Section 2.4 of Samelson's Notes on Lie Algebras](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4576720/96384).