# If $\alpha$ and $c \alpha$ are roots of a semisimple Lie algebra, then $c \in \{-1, 1\}$

Tags: lie-algebras, root-systems

Let $L$ be a semisimple Lie algebra over a field $F$ (which is algebraically closed with characteristic 0) and $\alpha$ and $c \alpha$ for $c \in F$ are roots of $L$. I want to prove that $c \in \{-1, 1\}$.

I know the argument for the statement: $\alpha$ is a root $\implies$ $-\alpha$ is a root. But I have not seen the argument for the above statement which means that the only possible multiples are $-\alpha$ and $\alpha$. I have looked here on StackExchange and in "Introduction to Lie algebras and representation theory" from Humphreys but have not found anything.

Comment: See the answer in the duplicate: *It follows that $\dim{\mathfrak g}_\alpha=1$ and $n\alpha\notin\Phi$ for all $n>1$.*

Comment: Compare also https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4583911/96384 and further links.

Comment: Section 8.4 in Humphreys explicitly proves this.